# protobuf based spring boot end point giving no output to swift client

Tags: swift, spring-boot, protobuf-java

I have a spring boot based micro-service endpoint which produces protobuf. Here is the .proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package TournamentFilterPackage;
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
option java_package = "com.mycompany.service.tournament.proto";
option java_outer_classname = "TournamentCompleteData";

message TournamentData {
    repeated  TournamentRecord tournamentRecords = 1;
}

message TournamentRecord {
   int64 id = 1;
   Date start = 2;
   float prize = 3;
   string name = 4;
   string speed = 5;
   string type = 6;
   float buyIn = 7;
   int32 noOfParticipants = 8;
   string status = 9;
}


message Date {
  int32 year = 1;
  int32 month = 2;
  int32 day = 3;
}
message PokerResponseProto {
repeated int32 errorCodes = 1;
google.protobuf.Any responseObject = 2;
}
```

Here is my rest controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value="Complete Tournament Data", response = PokerResponseProto.class)
    @GetMapping(value="/tournaments/completedata", produces = "application/x-protobuf")
    public ResponseEntity<PokerResponseProto> getCompleteTournamentdata() {
        
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("BEGIN::/lobby/api/v1//tournaments/completedata/ " + "GET ::");
        }
        List<TournamentTypeResponseDto> tournamentTypeResponseDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TournamentRecord> tournamentRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        ResponseEntity<PokerResponseProto> pokerResponse = null;
        try {
            tournamentTypeResponseDtos = 
            tournamentTypeDataService.getCompleteTournamentList();
            for(TournamentTypeResponseDto t:tournamentTypeResponseDtos) {
                tournamentRecords.add(controllerUtils.buildTournamentRecord(t));
            }
            TournamentData.Builder tournamentDataBuilder = 
            TournamentData.newBuilder().addAllTournamentRecords(tournamentRecords);
            pokerResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(BKPokerResponseProto.newBuilder()
                    .setResponseObject(Any.pack(tournamentDataBuilder.build()))
                    .build(), 
                    HttpStatus.OK);
            logger.info("pokerResponse: {}", pokerResponse.toString());
        } catch (PokerException pe) {
            if (this.logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
                this.logger.error(pe.getMessage(), bkpe);
            }
            List<Integer> errorCodeValue = controllerUtils
                    .convertErrorCodesToInt(bkpe.getErrorCodes());
            pokerResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(PokerResponseProto.newBuilder()
                    .addAllErrorCodes(errorCodeValue)
                    .build(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("RETURN::/lobby/api/v1//tournaments/completedata/ " + "GET :: {}", 
            pokerResponse.toString());
        }
        return pokerResponse;
    }
```

Here is the code snippet from ControllerUtils class:

```
   public TournamentRecord buildTournamentRecord(TournamentTypeResponseDto dto) {
        Instant tournamentStart = dto.getTournamentStartDate();
        LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(tournamentStart, 
                             ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
        Date.Builder dateBuilder1 = Date.newBuilder();
        dateBuilder1.setYear(localDate1.getYear());
        dateBuilder1.setMonth(localDate1.getMonthValue());
        dateBuilder1.setDay(localDate1.getDayOfMonth());
     TournamentCompleteData.Date trnamntStartDate = dateBuilder1.build();

   TournamentRecord tr = TournamentRecord.newBuilder()
        .setId(dto.getTournamentTypeId())
        .setStart(trnamntStartDate)
        .setPrize(dto.getFirstPrize())
        .setName(dto.getTournamentName())
        .setStatus(dto.getStatusName())
        .build();
   return tr;
   }
```

I have written a test-case which can access this end-point & print the tournaments. But Swift client gets null when it invokes this end point. Already existing protobuf end points work fine with swift client & I have a ProtobufHttpMessageConverter already configured

```
@Bean
ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

And when the swift client invokes the end point, log messages get printed. That means client is invoking the end-point.

Here is the swift client code snippet for LobbyAPI:

```
import Foundation
class LobbyAPI: Api {
    
    func getTournammentTableList(completion: @escaping ((TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentData?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    
    getData(WithUrl: (APIConstants.lobbyURL) + "tournaments/completedata/", APIKey: APIConstants.apiKey, completion: completion)
}
```

For TournamentTableListVM

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift

class TournamentTableListVM: NSObject {
    private weak var tblListView: LobbyTableListView!
    private var tblPreviewVM: TablePreviewVM!
    var arrFilterTableList: [LobbyFilterPackage_LobbyTableRecord] = []
    var arrTableList: [LobbyFilterPackage_LobbyTableRecord] = []
    var timer = Timer()
    var didSelectTable: ((_ tableRecord: LobbyFilterPackage_LobbyTableRecord,_ isObserver:Bool) -> Void)!
    var getFilterCallBack:(() -> Void)?
    var currentSelectedMoneyType: (() -> TabMenuMoneyToggleView.Money) = { .play }{
        didSet{
            tblPreviewVM.currentSelectedMoneyType = currentSelectedMoneyType
        }
    }
    
    var didTakeActionFromTablePreview: ((TablePreviewVM.TablePreviewPlayerActionType, Int) -> Void)?

    //For sorting
    var currentSortKey: String?
    var currentSortAscending: Bool?
    var aUserData: APPokerProto_PlayerProfileProto!
    var observClick = false

    func getCompleteTableData() {
        
        LobbyAPI().getTournammentTableList() {[weak self] (aTournammentData, aError) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            guard aError == nil, let tableData = aTournammentData, tableData.lobbyTableRecords.count > 0  else {
                
                self.emptyTableAndPreview()
                LoginManager.shared.didToggleNotify()
                return
            }
            LoginManager.shared.didToggleNotify()
            self.arrFilterTableList = tableData.lobbyTableRecords
            self.arrTableList = tableData.lobbyTableRecords
            self.tblListView.tblList.reloadData()
            self.tblListView.tblList.selectRowIndexes(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0) as IndexSet, byExtendingSelection: true)
            self.timeStamp = String(tableData.timeStamp.seconds)
        }
    }
```

In this above code "aTournammentData" is coming as nil.

**Update** Found that in front end swift, it was mapped to wrong generated swift struct. With the help of https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf plugin TournamentCompleteData.pb.swift file was generated as below

```
// DO NOT EDIT.
// swift-format-ignore-file
//
// Generated by the Swift generator plugin for the protocol buffer compiler.
// Source: TournamentCompleteData.proto
//
// For information on using the generated types, please see the documentation:
//   https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/

import Foundation
import SwiftProtobuf

// If the compiler emits an error on this type, it is because this file
// was generated by a version of the `protoc` Swift plug-in that is
// incompatible with the version of SwiftProtobuf to which you are linking.
// Please ensure that you are building against the same version of the API
// that was used to generate this file.
fileprivate struct _GeneratedWithProtocGenSwiftVersion: SwiftProtobuf.ProtobufAPIVersionCheck {
  struct _2: SwiftProtobuf.ProtobufAPIVersion_2 {}
  typealias Version = _2
}

struct TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentData {
  // SwiftProtobuf.Message conformance is added in an extension below. See the
  // `Message` and `Message+*Additions` files in the SwiftProtobuf library for
  // methods supported on all messages.

  var tournamentRecords: [TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentRecord] = []

  var unknownFields = SwiftProtobuf.UnknownStorage()

  init() {}
}

struct TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentRecord {
  // SwiftProtobuf.Message conformance is added in an extension below. See the
  // `Message` and `Message+*Additions` files in the SwiftProtobuf library for
  // methods supported on all messages.

  var id: Int64 = 0

  var start: TournamentFilterPackage_Date {
    get {return _start ?? TournamentFilterPackage_Date()}
    set {_start = newValue}
  }
  /// Returns true if `start` has been explicitly set.
  var hasStart: Bool {return self._start != nil}
  /// Clears the value of `start`. Subsequent reads from it will return its default value.
  mutating func clearStart() {self._start = nil}

  var prize: Float = 0

  var name: String = String()

  var speed: String = String()

  var type: String = String()

  var buyIn: Float = 0

  var noOfParticipants: Int32 = 0

  var status: String = String()

  var unknownFields = SwiftProtobuf.UnknownStorage()

  init() {}

  fileprivate var _start: TournamentFilterPackage_Date? = nil
}

struct TournamentFilterPackage_Date {
  // SwiftProtobuf.Message conformance is added in an extension below. See the
  // `Message` and `Message+*Additions` files in the SwiftProtobuf library for
  // methods supported on all messages.

  /// Year of the date. Must be from 1 to 9999, or 0 to specify a date without
  /// a year.
  var year: Int32 = 0

  /// Month of a year. Must be from 1 to 12, or 0 to specify a year without a
  /// month and day.
  var month: Int32 = 0

  /// Day of a month. Must be from 1 to 31 and valid for the year and month, or 0
  /// to specify a year by itself or a year and month where the day isn't
  /// significant.
  var day: Int32 = 0

  var unknownFields = SwiftProtobuf.UnknownStorage()

  init() {}
}

// MARK: - Code below here is support for the SwiftProtobuf runtime.

fileprivate let _protobuf_package = "TournamentFilterPackage"

extension TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentData: SwiftProtobuf.Message, SwiftProtobuf._MessageImplementationBase, SwiftProtobuf._ProtoNameProviding {
  static let protoMessageName: String = _protobuf_package + ".TournamentData"
  static let _protobuf_nameMap: SwiftProtobuf._NameMap = [
    1: .same(proto: "tournamentRecords"),
  ]

  mutating func decodeMessage<D: SwiftProtobuf.Decoder>(decoder: inout D) throws {
    while let fieldNumber = try decoder.nextFieldNumber() {
      // The use of inline closures is to circumvent an issue where the compiler
      // allocates stack space for every case branch when no optimizations are
      // enabled. https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/1034
      switch fieldNumber {
      case 1: try { try decoder.decodeRepeatedMessageField(value: &self.tournamentRecords) }()
      default: break
      }
    }
  }

  func traverse<V: SwiftProtobuf.Visitor>(visitor: inout V) throws {
    if !self.tournamentRecords.isEmpty {
      try visitor.visitRepeatedMessageField(value: self.tournamentRecords, fieldNumber: 1)
    }
    try unknownFields.traverse(visitor: &visitor)
  }

  static func ==(lhs: TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentData, rhs: TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentData) -> Bool {
    if lhs.tournamentRecords != rhs.tournamentRecords {return false}
    if lhs.unknownFields != rhs.unknownFields {return false}
    return true
  }
}

extension TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentRecord: SwiftProtobuf.Message, SwiftProtobuf._MessageImplementationBase, SwiftProtobuf._ProtoNameProviding {
  static let protoMessageName: String = _protobuf_package + ".TournamentRecord"
  static let _protobuf_nameMap: SwiftProtobuf._NameMap = [
    1: .same(proto: "id"),
    2: .same(proto: "start"),
    3: .same(proto: "prize"),
    4: .same(proto: "name"),
    5: .same(proto: "speed"),
    6: .same(proto: "type"),
    7: .same(proto: "buyIn"),
    8: .same(proto: "noOfParticipants"),
    9: .same(proto: "status"),
  ]

  mutating func decodeMessage<D: SwiftProtobuf.Decoder>(decoder: inout D) throws {
    while let fieldNumber = try decoder.nextFieldNumber() {
      // The use of inline closures is to circumvent an issue where the compiler
      // allocates stack space for every case branch when no optimizations are
      // enabled. https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/1034
      switch fieldNumber {
      case 1: try { try decoder.decodeSingularInt64Field(value: &self.id) }()
      case 2: try { try decoder.decodeSingularMessageField(value: &self._start) }()
      case 3: try { try decoder.decodeSingularFloatField(value: &self.prize) }()
      case 4: try { try decoder.decodeSingularStringField(value: &self.name) }()
      case 5: try { try decoder.decodeSingularStringField(value: &self.speed) }()
      case 6: try { try decoder.decodeSingularStringField(value: &self.type) }()
      case 7: try { try decoder.decodeSingularFloatField(value: &self.buyIn) }()
      case 8: try { try decoder.decodeSingularInt32Field(value: &self.noOfParticipants) }()
      case 9: try { try decoder.decodeSingularStringField(value: &self.status) }()
      default: break
      }
    }
  }

  func traverse<V: SwiftProtobuf.Visitor>(visitor: inout V) throws {
    // The use of inline closures is to circumvent an issue where the compiler
    // allocates stack space for every if/case branch local when no optimizations
    // are enabled. https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/1034 and
    // https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/1182
    if self.id != 0 {
      try visitor.visitSingularInt64Field(value: self.id, fieldNumber: 1)
    }
    try { if let v = self._start {
      try visitor.visitSingularMessageField(value: v, fieldNumber: 2)
    } }()
    if self.prize != 0 {
      try visitor.visitSingularFloatField(value: self.prize, fieldNumber: 3)
    }
    if !self.name.isEmpty {
      try visitor.visitSingularStringField(value: self.name, fieldNumber: 4)
    }
    if !self.speed.isEmpty {
      try visitor.visitSingularStringField(value: self.speed, fieldNumber: 5)
    }
    if !self.type.isEmpty {
      try visitor.visitSingularStringField(value: self.type, fieldNumber: 6)
    }
    if self.buyIn != 0 {
      try visitor.visitSingularFloatField(value: self.buyIn, fieldNumber: 7)
    }
    if self.noOfParticipants != 0 {
      try visitor.visitSingularInt32Field(value: self.noOfParticipants, fieldNumber: 8)
    }
    if !self.status.isEmpty {
      try visitor.visitSingularStringField(value: self.status, fieldNumber: 9)
    }
    try unknownFields.traverse(visitor: &visitor)
  }

  static func ==(lhs: TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentRecord, rhs: TournamentFilterPackage_TournamentRecord) -> Bool {
    if lhs.id != rhs.id {return false}
    if lhs._start != rhs._start {return false}
    if lhs.prize != rhs.prize {return false}
    if lhs.name != rhs.name {return false}
    if lhs.speed != rhs.speed {return false}
    if lhs.type != rhs.type {return false}
    if lhs.buyIn != rhs.buyIn {return false}
    if lhs.noOfParticipants != rhs.noOfParticipants {return false}
    if lhs.status != rhs.status {return false}
    if lhs.unknownFields != rhs.unknownFields {return false}
    return true
  }
}

extension TournamentFilterPackage_Date: SwiftProtobuf.Message, SwiftProtobuf._MessageImplementationBase, SwiftProtobuf._ProtoNameProviding {
  static let protoMessageName: String = _protobuf_package + ".Date"
  static let _protobuf_nameMap: SwiftProtobuf._NameMap = [
    1: .same(proto: "year"),
    2: .same(proto: "month"),
    3: .same(proto: "day"),
  ]

  mutating func decodeMessage<D: SwiftProtobuf.Decoder>(decoder: inout D) throws {
    while let fieldNumber = try decoder.nextFieldNumber() {
      // The use of inline closures is to circumvent an issue where the compiler
      // allocates stack space for every case branch when no optimizations are
      // enabled. https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/1034
      switch fieldNumber {
      case 1: try { try decoder.decodeSingularInt32Field(value: &self.year) }()
      case 2: try { try decoder.decodeSingularInt32Field(value: &self.month) }()
      case 3: try { try decoder.decodeSingularInt32Field(value: &self.day) }()
      default: break
      }
    }
  }

  func traverse<V: SwiftProtobuf.Visitor>(visitor: inout V) throws {
    if self.year != 0 {
      try visitor.visitSingularInt32Field(value: self.year, fieldNumber: 1)
    }
    if self.month != 0 {
      try visitor.visitSingularInt32Field(value: self.month, fieldNumber: 2)
    }
    if self.day != 0 {
      try visitor.visitSingularInt32Field(value: self.day, fieldNumber: 3)
    }
    try unknownFields.traverse(visitor: &visitor)
  }

  static func ==(lhs: TournamentFilterPackage_Date, rhs: TournamentFilterPackage_Date) -> Bool {
    if lhs.year != rhs.year {return false}
    if lhs.month != rhs.month {return false}
    if lhs.day != rhs.day {return false}
    if lhs.unknownFields != rhs.unknownFields {return false}
    return true
  }
}
```